# WPF Visualizing Model object

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I am just beginning to learn WPF with the MVVM Pattern.

At the moment I'm stuck on a problem where I want to graphically visualize my current Model object by drawing a shape with dimensions databound to the VM's current instance of my Model. (It should redraw itself when a property changes etc)

This is what I've achieved (almost how I want it to look..):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCjFW.png]

My current approach is to derive a class from the Shape class with some dependencyproperties databound to the Models properties. This worked just fine until I wanted to have different strokethicknesses etc for different parts of the shape.

What I've tried is separating the drawing into two custom shape objects (that will be enough for my flexibility demands at the moment), but the problem right now is that they will not align correctly and scale differently.

This is how it scales/aligns with two different custom shape objects:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a52J3.png]

I'm thinking that there is probably way more efficient and flexible ways to tackle this. Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell what layout panel you're using?

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're binding to a VM or not, the issue is scaling in your UI.  I don't think there are any "efficient and flexible" ways to handle this--you're doing pretty much low-to-the-wire UI work here.  Get your values from your VM (or wherever) and do that magic in your codebehind.

Comment: @Frank I'm currently positioning them in a Grid, earlier i positioned my single Shape in a ViewBox but it seems that a ViewBox will not take more than one shape.